# I don't understand if "per" meaning exact amount for each unit or does it mean "on average"

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-verbs

Does "per day" meaning exactly same amount every day, or deos it mean on average. For example if I say: he run 20 km per day during last 10 days. Does it mean that he run **exactly 20 km every day** during some period or does it mean that he run 200 km and if you divide it on the numbers of days it wold be the average of how many he run during a day? This is confusing.

Comment: Your sentence should be 'He **has** run 20 km per day during **the** last 10 days'.

Comment: I wouldn't assume 'exactly' - ie not 1mm more or less, but I would definitely expect every day to have included a run of 20km ±~250m . The example is a bit problematical because it's easy to run part of a kilometre. If you changed it to push-ups, then 20 per day means 20 on day 1, 20 on day 2, 20 on day 3 etc. It doesn't mean 10 on day 1, 20 on day 2 and 30 on day 3.

Comment: If your confusion is specifically with the word "per," it doesn't convey any more information than "each" or "every" would.  The rest is up to the reader/listener to infer - unless you specify it yourself, like in your bolded example (which could be written as "he ran exactly 20km per day")

Comment: Just to make things more confusing -- if I heard that sentence, I would assume neither exactly nor an average, but rather that the runner went a *minimum* of 20km each day. But for a prescription, it's probably intended to be exact; talking about what you're allowed to do (you can have 2 drinks per day) it's a maximum; talking about time spent on something (4 hours watching television per day) it's an average. I wouldn't be surprised if there are other implicit aggregation functions in other situations, too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case, it's not clear whether there's an implied meaning slightly different from the literal one.

The literal meaning of “20km per day” is indeed 20km each and every day: exactly 20km after the first day, 40km after the second, and so on.

However, the context may indicate that an average or approximation is intended.

It seems quite common (distressingly so, for those of us who like to be precise!) to omit any reference to averaging or rounding and leave the reader/listener to infer it. For a random example, [a web site](https://www.brake.org.uk/get-involved/take-action/mybrake/knowledge-centre/uk-road-safety) claims that:

> Every 22 minutes someone is killed or seriously injured on UK roads.

Given that road death rates almost certainly vary throughout the day as well as throughout the year, this is almost certainly an average over time; and the suspicious precision of the value is almost certainly an approximation too. So it should probably say “*On average*, every 22 minutes…”

That may well be the intent of the phrase in the question, too. But it's not stated, and since it would be entirely plausible to run exactly the same distance every day, we can only guess what the speaker intended.

Answer (score 14):

It could mean either, but as the meaning of "exactly 20km each day" would imply "an average of 20km each day", it is better to assume the second. It the given example, it probably doesn't matter much.

The speaker could easily clarify, if it makes a difference.

> He has run 20 km every day for the last 10 days.

> He has run an average of 20km per day for the last 10 days.

Similarly, there is nothing wrong with "there are 6.5 children per boat"  (if you have 13 children and two boats", it doesn't require cutting any children in half.

But on the other hand, if he had had done nothing for 9 days and then run 200km in one attempt, it would be odd to say "20 km per day".  Likewise "two pills per day" doesn't mean "wait 10 days then have 20". You have to be reasonable about this.

Answer (score 4):

"Per" comes from the Latin, which means "for" or "for each" in English. Therefore, "per day" means "for each day".

In **your example** of "he run 20 km **per day** during last 10 days", it means "he run 20 km **for each day** during last 10 days".

As you suggested, it is not average, it refers to a day. Another example would be "the doctor asked me to take 2 pills **per day**" = "the doctor asked me to take 2 pills **for each day**".

I hope it is more clear now :)

Comment: So if it says that someone: "scored 2 gals per game during season", it means that he **literally** scored 2 goals **in every game** of that season? It doesn't mean that he scored 2 goals on average during a season?

Comment: "per" can definitely mean average. Indeed common constructions like "GDP per capita" and "per cent" are always averages.

Comment: @FurtJunk in my opinion it really depends on the context. And I would say that in most cases it's **not** an average. When I read "per" I would assume it's not an average unless specifically "on average"  is mentioned or when it doesn't make sense in that situation

Comment: Similarly if a car has a fuel economy of "55 miles per gallon" doesn't mean that every gallon of fuel lasts for 55 miles. Once again it's an average (considered across a range of different driving conditions).

Comment: I agree with others that "per" can refer to averages, and I think "for each" can as well. If I said "in this community, there are 2 men *for each* woman", it wouldn't mean that each woman is assigned precisely 2 men, only that there are twice as many men as women. Most likely it would also be an approximation, e.g. there might be 23 women and 40 men.

Comment: @Ivo: No. In all cases it means an average unless explicitly stated otherwise. There are no counter-examples.

Answer (score 1):

> **Does "per day" mean the exactly same amount every day, or does it mean on average?** 
> So if it says that someone: "scored 2 goals per game during season", it means that he literally scored 2 goals in every game of that season? It doesn't mean that he scored 2 goals on average during a season?

Yes, the phrase "X per day" *literally* means that exactly X happens on each and every day.

The common example would be a doctor's note on a bottle of pills: "Take 1 per day until empty." which means to take 1 pill each day every day until you run out of pills.  (If you decide to "Take 7 pills every Monday." that would not be following the doctor's orders properly, despite the fact that '7 pills per week' has the same average as '1 pill per day'.)

---

However, casual-language often has more flexibility than strict legal-language or scientific-language.

If my friend said *"I've run 10km per day this week!"* it would be very very strange for me to reply *"You liar! I know for a fact that you ran 9km last Tuesday!"* because there is no good reason to be that exacting and pedantic during our casual conversation. (Unless I specifically want to be annoyingly pedantic for the purposes of mischievous teasing.)

Your "points per game" example might might often have a similar casual context.  While "Bob scored 2 points per game this season." would literally mean that he scored exactly 2 points on each and every game this season, two sports-fans discussing sports might decide that being annoyingly pedantic is not helpful to the conversation.  Furthermore, there are a number of ways to *soften* the statement compared to the *strict* literal definition, for example:

- "Bob scored around 2 points per game this season."
- "Bob scored 2 points per game over the course of this season."
- "Bob averaged 2 points per game this season."

All of these statements hint in different ways that the listener should understand these statements are not precisely equal to "Bob literally scored 2 points per game this season." and that they should assume some amount flexibility here or there.

Also, because sports discussions oftentimes invoke statistics, it may be the case that in a typical conversation phrases like "X points per game" are simply *assumed* to refer to average-values rather than literal-values.  As such, "Bob scored 2 points per game this season." might not be an example of the speaker/writer using "per game" imprecisely to mean "per game (on average)" but rather the speaker/writer using "points" imprecisely to mean "points (on average)".

Answer (score 0):

In a use like that, the most literal meaning is "divided by," or the solidus symbol( / ).  The meaning is equivalent to "20km/day."

You may notice that this doesn't answer your question on whether that value is average or specific. Unfortunately, that is ambiguous.

From context, I would guess that it's a specific value. You would usually see some sort of indication if it were an average value, but not always.